# Angles in triangle proof

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle. The lines $\iota_{1}$ and $\iota_{2}$ are perpendicular to $AB$ at the points $A$ and $B$, respectively. The perpendicular lines from the midpoint $M$ of $AB$ to the lines $AC$ and $BC$ intersect $\iota_{1}$ and $\iota_{2}$ at the point $E$ and $F$, respectively. If $D$ is the intersection point of the lines $EF$ and $MC$, prove that $$\angle ADB= \angle EMF.$$

Any help?  (JBMO 2015 Problem 3)

Comment: See [AoPS](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t48f6h1106922_jbmo_problem_3).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:Prove that angle EDC is 90 by using similar triangles.